# solving an equation by fixed point theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

This is captured from a chapter talking about completeness of metric space in Real Analysis, Carothers, 1ed. And I have been confused by an application of fixed point theorem:

The definition of fixed point theorem is:
[image]

An application of it is showed as following:

[image]
[image]

Why does the author consider the form of $f(x)=x-\lambda F(x)$? I mean how did he get this idea? It is a little interesting since the form looks like largange used in optimization. Well, just guessing.

Thanks^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to solve an equation $F(x)=0$ by a fixed point method. To do so, you must transform it into an equation of the form $f(x)=x$ for an appropriate $f$ with exactly the same solutions. The simplest choice is $x-F(x)=x$, leading to $f(x)=x-F(x)$. However the function $f$ may not satisfy the conditions of the fixed point theorem. So, after a little thinking, you may come up with the equation $x-\lambda\,F(x)=x$, $\lambda\ne0$, which has the same solutions as $F(x)=0$. It is very difficult to describe the chain of thoughts that lead to this; all I can say is that someone with experience in problem solving will think about it sooner or later.

The next problem is how to choose $\lambda$ in an optimal way, but that was not your question.

A further step is to consider the equation $x-H(F(x))=x$, where $H$ is defined on a neighborhood of $0$ and $H(x)=0$ if and only if $x=0$ (the previous method appears if we take $H(x)=\lambda\,x$.)

Comment: That does make a little sense^_^. BTW How to choose λ in an optimal way? I have seen that the answer of λ should be dropped off in the inverval of (1,1/6), which is so lofty here.

Comment: Suppose that you know that there is a solution in an interval $[a,b]$. Then you choose $\lambda$ so that i) $f([a,b])\subset[a,b]$ and ii) $\sup_{a\le x\le b}|f'(x)|$ is as small as possible.

Comment: why should supa≤x≤b|f′(x)| be as small as possible? If so, how to get range of value of the λ?

Comment: You want it to be $<1$ to be a contractive map. The smaller it is, the faster will converge the sequence of iterates.

Comment: oh, awesome! can i claim the λ in range of (0, 0.5) instead of (0,1/6)?

Comment: I already answered your original question. I think you should do the computations yourself.

Comment: Ok, i ll try to work it out, thanks a lot